# Pulling data from other system in Drupal

Tags: import, drupal-7

I'm a bit new to Drupal and have a task to import data periodically from other system.
So basically I've an endpoint that returns me an XML, I must to parse and put data into Drupal and then use these data (f.x. in dropdown lists)

What are the best practices to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand you are trying to achieve a periodic aggression from a external data source.

[Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module would be an excellent choice in here. Combined that with another contrib module [Feeds XPath parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) would help you configure it properly.

From Feeds Project Page,

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple
>   database records.
>
> One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content Import or
>   aggregate RSS/Atom feeds Import or aggregate CSV files Import or
>   aggregate OPML files PubSubHubbub support Create nodes, users,
>   taxonomy terms or simple database records from import Extensible to
>   import any other kind of content Granular mapping of input elements to
>   Drupal content elements Exportable configurations Batched import for
>   large files

From Feeds XPath Parser project page,

> Feeds XPath Parser is a Feeds plugin for parsing XML and HTML
>   documents. It enables site builders to leverage the power of Feeds to
>   easily import data from complex, external data sources. Each element
>   you wish to extract is setup using configurable mapping queries,
>   saving time for developers who would otherwise have to code complex,
>   specific-use modules. It also enables end-users to build web scrapers
>   and other useful tools within Drupal.
>
> You may need this module if you would like to:
>
> Import XML or HTML documents into nodes, users, taxonomy terms, or
>   regular database tables Scrape webpages like regular feed sources with
>   scheduling, updating, and expiring Extract content from HTML documents
>   to create a semantic data bank or mashup Features
>
> Builtin query debugger to assist with writing XPath queries Tidy
>   support for badly formatted markup Variable substitution, allowing you
>   to use the value from one or more queries as arguments in another
>   Various workarounds that cover up PHP’s idiosyncrasies with XPath

The details of implementation would be based on how you have configured your nodes in drupal.